# .NET Core API gets null from Angular POST

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, .net-core

I'm trying to POST data from Angular to my .NET Core API, but the incoming *data* is always null. See my code:

Here is my POST from Angular:

```js
public insertCategory(categoryToInsert: ICategoryDTO): Observable<ICategoryDTO> {
        const body: string = JSON.stringify(categoryToInsert);
        return this.httpClient.post<ICategoryDTO>(this.apiURL + 'Categories/new', categoryToInsert);
    }
```

ICategoryDTO being an object like this:

```js
export interface ICategoryDTO {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
}
export default ICategoryDTO;

//exemple object:
{Id: null, Name: "yyuyuy"}
```

This is what my API endpoint looks like on the .NET Core side:

```cs
[HttpPost("new")]
        [ProducesResponseType(201)]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        [ProducesResponseType(409)]
        [ProducesResponseType(500)]
        public IActionResult CreateWithAuthor([FromBody] CategoryDTO data)
        {
            var a = 1;
            return Ok(this._iCategoryBusiness.CreateWithAuthor(data));
        }
```

CategoryDTO being defined by this class:

```cs
using System;

namespace Back.DTO
{
    public class CategoryDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My problem**: I have a breakpoint at `var a = 1` and on that breakpoint `data` is always *null* when performing the post from my front-end. Doing it from Swagger works.

**What I have tried:** I have tried to stringify my object before passing it, which did nothing. I have also tried to pass a header along, both with stringified and non-stringified object, which did not work either. I changed the ICategoryDTO `Id` type from string to number but that did nothing.

Here's the header I have tried:

```js
header = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

With a request like this:

```js
public insertCategory(categoryToInsert: ICategoryDTO): Observable<ICategoryDTO> {
        const body: string = JSON.stringify(categoryToInsert);
        return this.httpClient.post<ICategoryDTO>(this.apiURL + 'Categories/new', body, {headers: this.header});
    }
```

Didn't work, same result.

Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: check your network tab in chrome when making the angular request, make sure that the headers for this request are what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by making my `Id` parameter not null, but 0 instead. I guess this makes sense because it isn't nullable on the .NET end. This took me two hours.